# GitHub Actions: capture multiple console lines from Gradle command

Tags: bash, gradle, github-actions

I have a job like below that runs on `ubuntu-latest`:

```
- name: Run Gradle
  id: run_gradle
  run: |
    echo "::set-output name=JOB::$(gradle run)\n"

- name: Test output
  run: echo "${{ steps.run_gradle.outputs.JOB }}"
```

This runs a Gradle task that outputs thousands of individual lines to the console. How can I capture all of the output from step `run_gradle`? My next goal would be to pass these lines to another workflow to parse and pick out pertinent lines for follow-on analysis.

As a test, I have tried to just capture and the re-print the output from `run_gradle` in the following step `Test output`. However, this step `run: echo "${{ steps.run_match.outputs.JOB }}"` just returns `echo ""`.

Additionally, when attempting this step below:

```
- name: Test output
  run: |
    while read -r LINE; do
    $LINE
    echo "$LINE"
    # do_something_with_it
    done < <(${{ steps.run_gradle.outputs.JOB }})
```

I get the following error from GitHub Actions:

```
Run while read -r LINE; do
  while read -r LINE; do
  $LINE
  echo "$LINE"
  # do_something_with_it
  done < <()
  shell: /bin/bash -e {0}
  env:
    JAVA_HOME_8.0.275_x64: /opt/hostedtoolcache/jdk/8.0.275/x64
    JAVA_HOME: /opt/hostedtoolcache/jdk/8.0.275/x64
    JAVA_HOME_8_0_275_X64: /opt/hostedtoolcache/jdk/8.0.275/x64
/home/runner/work/_temp/214ad176-0c5e-4903-a0b3-58969be12e44.sh: line 5: <(): ambiguous redirect
```

This implies to me that the `set-output:JOB` is not working to capture the output into a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It just print lines because you call `echo`, not command itself.

You can call it by:

```
run: ${{ steps.run_gradle.outputs.JOB }}
```

But it runs all at ones, like one big cmd. So more preferable way would be. Put the output to the file and then execute line by line.

```
- name: Gradle
  run: |
    gradle run >/tmp/gradle.out
- name: Test
  run: |
    while read -r LINE; do
      $LINE 
      # do_something_with_it
    done < /tmp/gradle.out
```

btw you have typo `steps.run_match` instead of `steps.run_gradle` in summary, it could explain empty output, if it's a case.

Comment: Thanks for your help - I tried your solution without avail unfortunately. I edited my question to demonstrate. Also thanks for pointing out the typo - I corrected that on SO.

Comment: OK, I see there would be a problem with the setout, maybe it's too long. I don't know the real output. But I edited my answer to use a temp file, which should works just fine, if you don't insist on variable.